# Saving android activity state

Tags: java, android

I just learned Android programming, and i have a problem.

I create an activity with a checkbox widget that is added programmatically or the checkbox widget will be added if the user touches the add button(tambah), the problem is how to save the state activity?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Variable Global
int checkId = 0; //CheckBox Id
EditText ex;
TextView noText;
LinearLayout m;
CheckBox check;
CheckBox noCheck;
String dat;
Toast errorNot;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void funcOne(View view) {

    /**
     * tambah.onClick function
     * @param ex - EditText variable
     * @param noText - TextView variable used for spacing
     * @param m - CheckBox main layout
     * @param check - Generated CheckBox widget
     * @param noCheck - Toggle between CheckBox and EditText
     * @param dat - EditText variable converted to String
     * @param errorNot - To display noData error
     */

    ex = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editData);
    noText = new TextView(this);
    m = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLayout);
    check = new CheckBox(this);
    noCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.noCheck);
    dat = ex.getText().toString();
    errorNot = Toast.makeText(this, "No input data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    // Method
    if (dat.length() > 1) {
        if (noCheck.isChecked()) {
            noText.setText(dat);
            m.addView(noText);
        } else {

            /**
             * @param n - New Toast (Only for debugging)
             */

            checkId ++;
            Toast n = Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(checkId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            check.setTag("ch"+checkId);
            check.setText(dat + " <WidgetTag " +check.getTag() + ">");
            m.addView(check);
            n.show();
        }
    } else {
        errorNot.show();
    }
}

public void addSpace(View view) {

    /**
     * space.onClick function
     * @param b - Child layout
     * @param d - TextView
     */

    LinearLayout b = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLayout);
    TextView d = new TextView(this);
    b.addView(d);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //outState.putBoolean("AstringKey", noCheck);
    outState.putString("AStringKey2", dat);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //savedInstanceState.getBoolean("AStringKey");
    savedInstanceState.getString("AStringKey2");
}
```

App Layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFs6M.jpg

Comment: Paste your code here instead of in the image you posted

Comment: What do you mean with saving state? Like when you close the app again or when your activity gets restarted (where savedInstanceState != null)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bundle parameter for onCreate() method in each activity. You can save instance in that. You can write code in onPause() so that before finishing activity it will store your content. You can again access it by using same bundle

Comment: So I need onPause() ? Because I have written onSaveInstanceState(), but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods available that can help you achieve this.

```
    @Override
            public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
// save your data into either or both of the parameters with the put### methods
            }
```

This method allows your activity to retain some of its data even after reboot. The data that you want to retain after reboot can be stored in the `PersistableBundle` object. The `Bundle` object is used in the same way as the one below.
This method however requires that some attributes be set on when you are starting this activity, you can read more on this in the android sdk documentation.

```
     @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
// save your data into either or both of the parameters with the put### methods
        }
```

This method only allows your activity to retain some data, but all the data will be cleared after a reboot. You can store all your necessary data in the `Bundle` object. This bundle will then be passed into your `onCreate` method the next time you return to this activity, provided you didn't destroy the activity instance.

The mistake in your code however is this;

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //savedInstanceState.getBoolean("AStringKey");
    savedInstanceState.getString("AStringKey2");// you are not assigning this to the dat variable.
// it should rather be
dat = savedInstanceState.getString("AStringKey2");
}
```

Comment: Are you pressing the back key? If not, then try and do a debug by placing breakpoints at where ever the dat variable was used.

Comment: The problem is: when the application changes orientation, the checkbox widget disappears, I try to press the back button, then open the application, there is no checkbox widget, the application is empty

Comment: It is the back button that kills your activity. Every change in orientation also causes your activity to be restarted.
And I don't see you trying to save your views either. You could try and save a tag for each view on the screen. Although you have tags for some views, I don't see you updating the `dat` variable in the part where you are setting the tag.
Can you update the question with the entire code for MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Override protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  //savedInstanceState.getBoolean("AStringKey");  dat = savedInstanceState.getString("AStringKey2");  noCheck.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("noCheckBox"));Toast n = Toast.makeText(this, "onRestoreInstanceState called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  n.show(); }